# Regex with comma delimited string seperated by pipe sign in .NET

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to get a regex for the following format below.  It requires a "Name", any character except empty whitespace or nothing.  A pipe sign always, then a list of items comma seperated, which can be any characters. The comma cant have a space after it though (, ).

```
Name|Item1,Item2,Item3
```

Below is what I have so far and its matching basically every time.

```
(.*)|([.*]+(,[\S]+)*)+
```

**Invalids**

```
Name|
Name
   |Item1,Item2
|Item1,Item2
Name|Item1, Item2
|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^[^|\s]+\|[^,|\s]+(?:,[^,|\s]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B%5E%7C%5Cs%5D%2B%5C%7C%5B%5E%2C%7C%5Cs%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%2C%5B%5E%2C%7C%5Cs%5D%2B%29*%5Cr%3F%24&i=Name%7CItem1%2CItem2%2CItem3%0D%0AName%7C%0D%0AName%0D%0A%20%20%20%7CItem1%2CItem2%0D%0A%7CItem1%2CItem2%0D%0AName%7CItem1%2C%20Item2%0D%0A%7C&o=m)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^|\s]+` - one or more chars other than `|` and whitespace
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `[^,|\s]+` - one or more chars other than `,`, `|` and whitespace
- `(?:,[^,|\s]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of a comma and then one or more chars other than `,`, `|` and whitespace
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: @MikeFlynn No, then use `^[^|]+\|[^,|\s]+(?:,[^,|\s]+)*$`

Comment: Can the comma seperated list have whitespace in between the commas? Just not at the start or end.

Comment: @MikeFlynn Yes, `^[^|]+\|[^,|\s]+(?:\s*,\s*[^,|\s]+)*$`

Comment: This doesnt match anymore, `Name|test test,test`, `(whitespace)|test,test`, `Name|test, test`

Comment: @MikeFlynn I misinterpreted your intention. I think you need `^[^|]+\|[^,|]+(?:,[^,|]+)*$`

Comment: This still seems to not match `Name|test,dsfd, d`

Comment: It should not have space before or after conman delimited items.

Comment: It [matches](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5e%7c%5d%2b%5c%7c%5b%5e%2c%7c%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%2c%5b%5e%2c%7c%5d%2b%29*%24&i=Name%7ctest%2cdsfd%2c+d&o=m) `Name|test,dsfd, d`

Comment: Sorry it should be invalid like in the examples

Comment: @MikeFlynn Then use `^[^|]+\|[^,|\s]+(?:\s+[^,|\s]+)*(?:,[^,|\s]+(?:\s+[^,|\s]+)*)*$`